# Multiple IF conditions in a python list comprehension

Tags: python, conditional-statements, list-comprehension

I was wondering, is it possible to put multiple `if` conditions in a list comprehension? I didn't find anything like this in the docs.

I want to be able to do something like this

```
ar=[]
for i in range(1,n):
  if i%4 == 0: ar.append('four')
  elif i%6 == 0: ar.append('six')
  else: ar.append(i)
```

using a list comprehension. How can I do it?

Is this even possible? If its not, what would be the most elegant (pythonic) way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

How about

```
ar = [('four' if i % 4 == 0 else ('six' if i % 6 == 0 else i)) for i in range(1, n)]
```

For example, if `n = 30` this is

```
[1, 2, 3, 'four', 5, 'six', 7, 'four', 9, 10, 11, 'four', 13, 14, 15, 'four', 17, 'six', 19, 'four', 21, 22, 23, 'four', 25, 26, 27, 'four', 29]
```

ETA: Here's how you could apply a list of conditions:

```
CONDITIONS = [(lambda i: i % 4 == 0, "four"), (lambda i: i % 6 == 0, "six"),
              (lambda i: i % 7 == 0, "seven")]

def apply_conditions(i):
    for condition, replacement in CONDITIONS:
        if condition(i):
            return replacement
    return i

ar = map(apply_conditions, range(0, n))
```

Comment: Thanks! I believe this way I can add any number of conditions to it. Though the code will be incomprehensible!

Comment: See my edit. I'm sure you can figure out the remainder (but if not I can help)

Comment: (My original neglected to make them lambda statements, current version would work though)

Comment: Ok so that's a `list` of conditions, but how do I use them in the list comprehension? And also, to put *i* in the list (when *i* is not divisible by any number), the code should be such that it knows when none of the conditions in `conditions` are true.

Comment: Yes this is good. I didn't know about a 2 variable for loop. Thanks!

Comment: That's just tuple unpacking- it could also have been done as `for c in conditions: if c[0](i): return c[1]` (the unpacked version is just clearer)

Answer (score 15):

You can put you logic in a separate function, and then have the elegance of the list comprehension along with the readability of the function:

```
def cond(i):
    if i % 4 == 0: return 'four'
    elif i % 6 == 0: return 'six'
    
    return i

l=[cond(i) for i in range(1,n)]
```

If you have lots of conditions, it is usually easier to maintain a single dict rather than a big if/else ladder:

```
def cond(i):
    mkey={4:'four',6:'six'}
    return next((mkey[k] for k in mkey if i%k == 0), i)
```

This uses the default version of next to find if any integer key is a multiple of that key or the number itself, the default, if not.

Which could be a single comprehension if desired:

```
[next((v for k,v in {4:'four',6:'six'}.items() if i%k==0), i) for i  in range(1,10)]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
ar = ["four" if i%4==0 else "six" if i%6==0  else i for i in range(1,30)]
```